# "SHOW" function returns error on Mac OS X

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm creating an automated data entry User form in Excel. I have the first part written in Excel on Windows because Mac doesn't support "UserForm". I've tried to check my User Form on a Mac and I get this error:

> "Run-Time error "380
>   Could not set the RowSource property. Invalid property value."

I've tried to find some answers how to fix this and switch it to a Mac but didn't find anything. I'm not a coder. I'm using some videos and tutorials to make that form for my propose. Data in the form is temporary.

I attached some screenshot of how my form looks, what kind of error I get, and the code where I have the error.
Also code here:

---

```
Sub Show_Form()
    frmForm.Show
End Sub
```

---

I need to mention that my user form work perfectly on Windows.

---

**Full code from module1:**

```
Sub Reset()

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] ' idetifying the last row

    With frmForm

        .txtID.Value = ""
        .txtName.Value = ""
        .optMale.Value = False
        .optFemale.Value = False


        .cmbDepartment.Clear

        .cmbDepartment.AddItem "HR"
        .cmbDepartment.AddItem "Operation"
        .cmbDepartment.AddItem "Training"
        .cmbDepartment.AddItem "Quality"

        .txtCity.Value = ""
        .txtCountry.Value = ""

        .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 9
        .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True

        .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "30,60,75,40,60,45,55,70,70"

        If iRow > 1 Then

            .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:I" & iRow
        Else

            .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:I2"
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Submit()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

    iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] + 1

    With sh

        .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 1

        .Cells(iRow, 2) = frmForm.txtID.Value

        .Cells(iRow, 3) = frmForm.txtName.Value

        .Cells(iRow, 4) = IIf(frmForm.optFemale.Value = True, "Female", "Male")

        .Cells(iRow, 5) = frmForm.cmbDepartment.Value

        .Cells(iRow, 6) = frmForm.txtCity.Value

        .Cells(iRow, 7) = frmForm.txtCountry.Value

        .Cells(iRow, 8) = Application.UserName

        .Cells(iRow, 9) = [Text(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:SS")]


    End With

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Show_Form()

    frmForm.Show

End Sub
```

---

**Full code from userForm**

```
Private Sub cmdReset_Click()

    Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult

    msgValue = MsgBox("Do you want to Reset the form?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")

    If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    Call Reset


End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

    Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult

    msgValue = MsgBox("Do you want to save the data?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")

    If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    Call Submit
    Call Reset

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Call Reset

End Sub
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error is likely to be in your `frm.Show.Initialize` sub. You'll need to post **that** if anyone is going to be able to help you.

Comment: What do you mean **That**?? Full code?

Comment: Yes. Post the code for `UserForm_Initialize()` if you need quick and accurate help :)

Comment: I hope its correct one ;).     `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Call Reset

End Sub`

Comment: Hi Christof, although the error is 'pointing' at the yellow highlighted line, it's actually erroring somewhere within the code that is called by the highlighted line. So in this case, probably within the `Sub UserForm_Initialize`. However, as that calls the `Reset` sub, you're going to need to share that also. Either that, or Step through your code (F8 on windows, not sure on Mac) line by line until it errors. Then you'll know the **real** culprit. Somewhere in your Reset code is a line that is setting the `RowSource` property. It is likely around there.

Comment: Hi CLR, I try to find something but I don't see anything wrong. I've also check my code with vid tutorial and I got everything the same. And still that code work perfectly on Windows. I edit my post with full code which I have.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create Database worksheet

[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

just change 'Form_Initialize()' to 'frmForm_Initialize()' on this line code

Private Sub Form_Initialize()

Call Reset

End Sub

Comment: Please format any code in your response.  As it is, your code response is difficult to read.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).